# How can I load layers from oracle with the python editor that comes with Qgis?

Tags: pyqgis, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I have tried to add a layer from the Oracle database with SDO_GEOMETRY geometry, from the console that comes in QGIS, but it does not load anything, I occupy this because I want to put it in a plugin.

How can I load layers from oracle with the python editor that comes with Qgis?

```
SqlT = "select TABLE_NAME from all_tab_columns where data_type = 'SDO_GEOMETRY' and owner= 'GEOSERVER'"
cur.execute(sqlT)
tables = cur.fetchall()
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("x.x.x.x","port","database","user","pass")

QgsProject.instance().writeEntry('WFSLayers',"/",[]) #investigar

for t in tables:
    print str(t[0])

uri.setDataSource(' ', str(t[0]), "GEOMETRY")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), str(t[0]), 'oracle')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  What happens when you run that code?  Does it do anything or give any errors?  Please [edit] your question to include this information.